# How to change xticks of bar chart according to values of first dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, xticks

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
data = {'QA Score': [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7],
   'Scopus': [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,3,2,3,6,4,2],
   'ResearchGate': [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,3,2,1,0,2,1],
   'Taylor&Francis': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0],
   'ACM': [0,0,0,0,1,1,3,3,0,4,2,5,0,0,0]
  }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to create a stacked bar plot with the numbers of the column 'QA score' as xticks.

Right now I have got this plot:

[image: stacked bar plot]

The x axis from 0 to 14 should be set to 0 to 7 with steps of 0.5 (as in column 'QA score')

I tried resetting the index with `df.set_index(['QA Score'])` and tried `plt.xticks()` but it all does not work.

Anyone has an idea how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No reason to set the column as the index `ax = df.plot(kind='bar', x='QA Score', stacked=True, rot=0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
df.set_index('QA Score').plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

output:

[image: stacked bar plot]

Comment: @Luc maybe provide the syntax you had in your question, it might help others in the future ;)